# Expiry date alert 30 days before expiry

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way for me, with a WPF application, to schedule an alert message to be shown 30 days before expiry date?
What I have is a ValidFromDate, ValidToDate of user subscription.

Comment: Please explain when you expect this to be shown. Is it when the app is initially opened?

Comment: Yes, there is...

Comment: `if(DateTime.Now == ValidToDate.AddDays(-30))`

Comment: @SeM It will never hit if the time deviates 2 milliseconds.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I didn't really meant to answer OP's question, just some kind of quick hint in comments. But yes, you're right, in his case better use `>=`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you all. As John mentioned I need it when the app is initially opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
var ValidToDate = new DateTime(2018, 11, 14); // this date is just an example
var expiriesInDays = (int)(ValidToDate - DateTime.Now).TotalDays; // calculate remaining days
if(expiriesInDays <= 30) // you can change the expression to equals if you just want show this message for the specific day when there are 30 days left
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Your subscription will end in {expiriesInDays} days");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime date= ValidToDate.AddDays(-30);
```

Comment: That doesn't schedule an alert message, as asked.

Comment: We can convert date to string and alert it’s value, or compare it to DateTime.Now()

Comment: I already tried this method. It didn't give me what I expected

Answer (score 0):

As you had mentioned, you are having ValidToDate,

then you can check the expiry before 30 days like,

```
if(currentDate == ValidToDate.AddDays(-30))
{
  // do your logic
}
```

Comment: And what if the time deviates 2 milliseconds? Then the `if` will never hit.

Comment: if your intention is only about date means, you can check the Date alone, if(currentDate.Date==ValidToDate.AddDays(-30).Date)